# ClassCastException when converting json to "scala.collection.immutable.HashMap" when entries are less

Tags: scala, apache-spark, json4s

I using json4s for converting a json to scala.collection.immutable.HashMap. But it fails with 
`java.lang.ClassCastException: scala.collection.immutable.Map$Map3 cannot be cast to scala.collection.immutable.HashMap`
when entries in json are less than five. It works perfectly with five or more entries.

checked json is correct and this should not be issue.

```
implicit val formats = Serialization.formats(NoTypeHints)

read[scala.collection.immutable.HashMap[String, Config]](json).get(id)
```

```
case class Config(joinConfig: JoinConfig,
                         a: Option[Boolean],
                         b: Option[Boolean],
                         c: Option[Boolean]) {}

case class JoinConfig(d: Double,e: Double,f: Double) {}
```

Is this scala Map behavior or json4s issue?

Comment: I guess it's related to the different representation of smaller hashmaps: [Note: The builder of this hash map may return specialized representations for small maps.](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.1/scala/collection/immutable/HashMap.html)

Comment: scala.collection.immutable.Map$Map3 can be cast to Map.
read should work with Map instead of HashMap like 
`read[Map[String, Config]]`

Comment: Scala immutable map https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.1/scala/collection/immutable/Map.html have subclass Map1,Map2,Map3 and Map4 https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.1/scala/collection/immutable/Map$$Map4.html and i think issue is with how they store values. I will try using read[Map[String, Config]] see how this will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is Scala behavior. The `Map.apply(pair: T*)` returns special instances of `Map` based the size. A map with 3 elements does not require a hash table, its more efficient to just compare each key.

As Yuriy says in his comment you should just use the `Map` trait and leave the implementation up to scala.